# Hag alignment change: what happens should they become forcibly 'good'?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, planes

Imagine a night hag grows tired of her untrustworthy coven's backstabbing and betrayal - she decides enough is enough. Over many weeks of trial and error she eventually takes these lesser hags, ties them up, stuffs them in her *Bag of Holding* and uses her *Plane Shift (self only)* to Bytopia. She dumps them there in prisons until their alignment changes. When they are eventually / inevitably / completely good (in some *neutrally* or *lawfully* way), she brings her companions back somewhere in the Prime Material realms.

> **Optional Rule: Pervasive Goodwill**
>
> At the end of each long rest taken on [Bytopia], a visitor that is neither lawful good nor neutral good must make a DC 10 Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature’s alignment changes to lawful good or neutral good (whichever is closer to the creature’s current alignment). The change becomes permanent if the creature doesn’t leave the plane within 1d4 days.
>
> [*Dungeon Master's Guide*, [Chapter 2: Creating a Multiverse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#Bytopia)]

How would the newly minted 'extremely good' hags function? I have virtually dozens of far reaching campaign ideas on this, all of which i am afraid to use: a DM's job is to create credible, believable and somewhat RAW plot-consistent stories. This whole thing may simply be an unworkable mess, so i have come to the good folks of Stack Exchange for help.

Long story short: what happens to this coven? Could this work as a long-term Big Bad Evil-Good Group (BBEGG?) - or would they simply go thermal nuclear upon re-entry to the Prime Material?

Comment: What type of hags are these "lesser hags"

Comment: I'm not sure if we can offer a definitive answer on this. Is there a rule about their alignment you might be referencing specifically?

Comment: Are you asking if the hags can be 'good' due to the forceful alignment change or are you asking if a coven can exist between hags who are not all evil?

Comment: Seconding Premier Bromanov, when it comes to alignment you're either asking about the mechanics (of which there are precious few in 5e) or the behavioral implications ([which this format doesn't support](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357)). If you're asking about how a particular rule about alignment interacts with the newly good hags, or if there is such a rule that would interact, that's workable, but we need to know which.

Comment: As i feared, this concern cannot be answered in this medium. My thanks to all for looking into this and best wishes to everyone involved.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the one evil hag enslaved the others in some way, they probably wouldnt work smoothly as the villain of a story since a good aligned hag probably wouldn't accept going about their usual hag business.

I'd actually say they would backstab her even more now that they are good and the leader is evil.